# Error in fct_05_m_railway_invoice: UndefinedColumn - railway_name not recognized

Tags: sql, postgresql, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

1. I have modified all the SQL scripts to extend two fields in ods.fct_05_railway_name: I started with the ODS layer, then went through the source tables (dm_kzd_ev1, dm_kzd_ev7, dm_kzd_ev11), and then through the intermediate data marts (dm_kzd_daily_1 > dm_kzd_daily_2 > dm_kzd_daily_3 > dm_kzd_daily_4) and the daily data mart (dm_kzd_daily). Created DDL.

DB - PostgreSQL

DDL:

```
ALTER TABLE ods.fct_05_m_railway_invoice
ADD COLUMN railway_code int4,
ADD COLUMN railway_name varchar(20); 

 
ALTER TABLE dm.dm_kzd_ev1 
ADD column railway_code int4, 
ADD COLUMN railway_name varchar(20); 
   
ALTER TABLE dm.dm_kzd_ev7 
add column railway_code int4, 
ADD COLUMN railway_name varchar(20); 

etc
```

2. I triggered the DAG for data loading to check if everything is working properly.

I encountered an error in the fct_05_m_railway_invoice task:

The error log shows:

> Log file does not exist:
> /usr/local/airflow/logs/dag_id=1_1_ETL_LoadODS_prod/run_id=scheduled__2023-10-10T06:30:00+00:00/task_id=fct_05_group.fct_05_m_railway_invoice/attempt=2.log
>
> psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "railway_name" does not exist
> LINE 5:
> ...tion,close_size_faction,recipient_id,railway_code,railway_na...
> ^
> HINT: There is a column named "railway_name" in the table
> "fct_05_m_railway_invoice", but it cannot be referenced from this part
> of the query.

I have already analyzed the table and confirmed that the fields are present. However, there seems to be an issue with data transfer and why these fields are not being recognized.

I was expecting the data to flow into the ODS first, and then to the DM layer.

Comment: `column "railway_name" does not exist LINE 5: ...tion,close_size_faction,recipient_id,railway_code,railway_na... ^` Do you have full text for this SQL query?